# Why ng-controller and ng-repeat doesn't work together inside same tag in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The below code is not working since i used both ng-controller and ng-repeat inside same tag. But if i use ng-repeat inside child div, its working. Why?

```
**Not Working**
<div ng-controller="myController" ng-repeat= "object in objectArray">
{{object.State}}
{{oject.Capital}}
</div>


**Working**
<div ng-controller="myController" >
<div ng-repeat= "object in objectArray">
{{object.State}}
{{oject.Capital}}
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No way, both should work.. Could you please provide us plunkr/fiddle of the non working code?

Comment: because in the **Not Working** version you're repeating the controller itself multiple times so it will never work, but in the **Working** version you have only one controller and you're repeating the objects in the objectArray

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here:

**The Logical Reason:**

```
<div ng-controller="myController" ng-repeat= "object in objectArray">
{{object.State}}
{{oject.Capital}}
</div>
```

As you know, ng-repeat is multiplicating the containing tag, so here, there will be a lot of controllers on the same page like this:

```
<div ng-controller="myController" ng-repeat= "object in objectArray">
    lorem
    ipsum
</div>
<div ng-controller="myController" ng-repeat= "object in objectArray">
    lorem
    ipsum
</div>
<div ng-controller="myController" ng-repeat= "object in objectArray">
    lorem
    ipsum
</div>
```

So this is why you cannot use them in the same tag, you have to separate them like you did in your second example.

**The Main Reason:**

Also, the main logic is, you can manage the components inside the controller's ones, not others; so your angular components that you want to manage like ng-repeat, ng-if or ng-model they all should be inside a unique controller tag, not at the same level.

To provide this, AngularJS library gives priority to the components like controllers have the highest ones than the other components like ng-repeat has lower, so the controller tag will be compiled first and then the others. If the compiler sees some errors like syntactical errors, it will inform the coder to not to do those.

You can read more about the priorities in AngularJS [here](https://newyyz.com/blog/2014/12/15/understanding-priorities-in-angularjs-directive-definition-objects/).

Comment: Thank u webmaster. :)

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs, `ng-repeat` as a directive has a priority of 1000, and `ng-controller` a priority of 500, meaning that `ng-repeat` will get compiled first, and the `objectArray` array you are referring to is bound to the scope of `myController` which has not been initialized yet, so `ng-repeat` will in that case fail.

Nice post about directive priority: [1](http://www.newyyz.com/blog/2014/12/15/understanding-priorities-in-angularjs-directive-definition-objects/)

Comment: Thank u Pierre Rai